# Xamarin messaging plugin: Autodial in IOS and UWP

Tags: xamarin, messaging

I'm using the Xamarin Messaging plugin and in android you can set the Autodial property to true to make a call without user interaction.

But I cannot set this property in UWP or IOS. Is it possible to make a call in without user interaction in this systems?

Thanks

Comment: the [docs](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xam.plugins.messaging) say Android only

Comment: No, Android is the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xam.plugins.messaging) this is an Android only feature.